# How to validate the email format after a user has entered an email in an input using php and return the email of the user?

Tags: php, html, input, filter-validate-email

I'm a beginner and have an input where a user can enter an optional email. I would like to make sure if the user enters something, the email format is correct.
I do have a syntaxe error trying to use "&&" but I'm pretty sure it's possible to check 2 conditions (not empty and correct format) in one if.
I would also like to replace the echo with the email the user has entered.

Here is the html code

```
<div method="post">
<label for="email">Email:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</div>
```

And the PHP

```
$var = "email";

if (!empty($var)) && (filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === true){
    echo "an email has been entered";
 }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Check your parentheses, for instance, the one after `empty($var)` shouldn't be there if you want to continue inside the `if (....)`.

Comment: Also `filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` will never return `true`. If the email is invalid, it returns `false`, but if it's valid, it will return the email.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite close actually. As noted in the comments, your parenthesis don't fit and [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) won't return true but the email address (which should be truthy).

So your code should look like this:

```php
$var = "email";

if (!empty($var) && filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "an email has been entered";
}
```